# Orientation is always portrait when coming from background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When my app returns from background it always rotates to portrait. In my VC -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

`interfaceOrientation` is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out orientation in that VC with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check your orientation settings in your project's plist.